# How do I fix a wordpress jetpack fatal error please?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, crm, jetpack

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "jetpack_boost_admin_missing_files" not found or invalid function name in C:\Users\hp\Local Sites\enfants-prcieux-bijoux\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:308 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\hp\Local Sites\enfants-prcieux-bijoux\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 C:\Users\hp\Local Sites\enfants-prcieux-bijoux\app\public\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 C:\Users\hp\Local Sites\enfants-prcieux-bijoux\app\public\wp-admin\admin-header.php(303): do_action('admin_notices') #3 C:\Users\hp\Local Sites\enfants-prcieux-bijoux\app\public\wp-admin\admin.php(239): require_once('C:\Users\hp\Loc...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\Users\hp\Local Sites\enfants-prcieux-bijoux\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308

Anybody ever had this ?

kind regards

I was trying to connect Jetpack CRM with woo commerce

Answer (score 0):

Probably something went wrong during copying or updating Jetpack CRM plugin. Download the plugin files again and override it inside */**wordpress_installation**/wp-content/plugins/**jetpack_crm_plugin_folder***

If will doesn't help try to move Jetpack CRM plugin folder outside the *plugins* folder to disable it. That will make you sure the only reason for fatal error it's Jetpack CRM plugin itself.

If the overriding doesn't help and you make sure the only reason of fatal error it's plugin exactly - the best solution would be to contact the authors.